# Why cmd cannot read paths that contain words in a language different from English?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this batch script for copying between two folders:

```
xcopy /y "C:\Users\_____\workspace" "D:\Backup_for_project"
pause
```

Where the empty line there: ____  is my name in a langauge different from English.
The cmd doesn't recognize this and I get an error that path doesn't exsits.

My script works if the words in the path are in English only.

How can I fix it so that the cmd will also recognize this specific word?

Comment: What about using `%UserName%` instead or navigating to `"%UserProfile%"` first then just RoboCopying `"workspace"`. _XCopy is an outdated command which was superceded as far back as Vista._

Comment: CMD is a Unicode application; however, batch scripts are decoded line-by-line using the current console codepage, which defaults to the OEM codepage of the system locale. If you created the batch file in notepad it's probably saved using the ANSI codepage. You can get the current console codepage via `chcp.com` and set a new one using `chcp.com [CODEPAGE]`. You can get the ANSI codepage from `wmic os get codeset /value`.

Comment: It's straight-forward to use `for /f` loops to save the current codepage as `CP_CURRENT` and the system ANSI codepage as `CP_ANSI`. Then on the line before the xcopy.exe command you can switch to the ANSI codepage to ensure it gets decoded properly, and immediately after the xcopy command, switch back to the previous codepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO using `%USERPROFILE%` is the easier way, but to follow eryksun's hints:

```
@Echo off

:: to be language independent I use two For /F first split : 
:: then trim spacce and possible . (in German for example)
For /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A in ('chcp'
) Do For /F "delims=. " %%B in ("%%A") Do set "CP_Current=%%B"

:: to remove UTF16 conversion remnants (cr,cr,lf) of wmic
:: here also a double for is required
For /F %%A in ('wmic os get codeset /value^|find "="'
) Do For /F %%B in ("%%A") Do Set %%B

:: Switch codepage
Echo Switching to codepage %CodeSet%
chcp %CodeSet%

Echo do whatever you like with codepage %CodeSet%
Timeout /T 10

:: Switch back to saved codepage
Echo Switching back to codepage %CP_Current%
chcp %CP_Current%
Timeout /T 10
```

Comment: @eryksun No `%%B` contains `CodeSet=1252`

Comment: Ok, I missed that. I had written my test differently using `"skip=2 tokens=2 delims=="` instead of using find.exe. Your way is more reliable.

Comment: FYI, wmic.exe only writes UTF-16 to disk files. It writes OEM encoded text to the console and to pipes. What it does here that's weird is write newlines as CRCRLF, so an extra CR character remains in the string. That's what your second `for /f` loop removes. In my test for this I used a substring to remove it instead of a second loop.

Comment: @eryksun If you pipe wmic output to a hex viewer you will see there are `0D 0D 0A` sequences (also being part of variable content), the second stacked for removes te double `0D`.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, just a remnant from the conversion.

Comment: I've seen that claim before, but I doubt it since wmic does its work in native Unicode strings and only encodes at the last step when writing to stdout if it's a pipe or console. It calls an ntdll.dll runtime library function to do the encoding. Converting CRLF from the native UTF-16 to the OEM codepage is a simple cast from 16-bit `wchar_t` values to 8-bit `char` values; there should be no remnant CR character. Anyway, I'm doing some system updates at the moment, but in a couple minutes I'll be able to attach a debugger and confirm exactly what's happening.

Comment: I don't accuse wmic, but as a matter of fact these double `0D` remnants are a nuisance to be filtered or otherwise you could get strange effetcs when concatenating/echoing strings containing the superfluous `0D`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I inspected the situation. I do blame wmic.exe -- but not because of a botched character encoding. What happens is that wmic calls msvcrt `fprint` to write a string such as `"CodeSet=1252\r\n"` to stdout. The problem is that the file is opened in text mode, which means the CRT converts `"\n"` (linefeed) to `"\r\n"` (return + linefeed). wmic is at fault because it's passing an improperly formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested to know if this works for you.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command Copy-Item -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE/workspace" -Destination "D:\Backup_for_project" -Recurse
```